# jQuery TinyMCE with wordcount plugin

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm currently trying to get the "wordcount" plugin working with TinyMCE for jQuery.  I'm not using any other TinyMCE plugins at the moment.  Based on the limited TinyMCE documentation that I've been able to find, this should be a straightforward option that gets added to the TinyMCE init, but this config is not loading anything at all.  I've searched high and low for tips as to what might be the problem, but cannot find anything.  (I'm well aware of how terrible the documentation for TinyMCE is)

The form is being rendered from Rails 3.2.12, the jQuery plugin for TinyMCE is included in the asset pipeline in my application.js file, and I'm using the following coffeescript code to init the TinyMCE editor:

```
$('main_form').find('textarea.wysiwig').tinymce
    script_url: '/assets/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',
    plugins: "wordcount",
    content_css : '/assets/editor.css',
    theme : "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,bullist,numlist",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "wordcount",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    valid_elements: "strong/b,em/i,ol,ul,li,br"
```

I've included the wordcount in the second button set in order to try to isolate what is happening, but this produces the following JS error within TinyMCE: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Button' of undefined"  (I'm using Chrome to test and the editor works fine without the plugin option)

Any pointers on what to try or whether it just doesn't work would be great to hear.

Answer (score 0):

`wordcount` does not have a button. If you have loaded it in the plugin config setting tinymce will show you the number of words in a html element below your editor.

Comment: Ah, yes, pretty foolish to expect a button to display the word count....  I guess that's frustration getting the better of me.But adding the wordcount plugin on it's own does nothing on my form.  No wordcount appears before, during or after typing in the editor.  Is there additional config or DOM elements that I'm missing?

Comment: you need to have theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom". the wordcount should be located in the right corner of that bar. have a cloaser look at this description too: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:theme_advanced_statusbar_location